# TreeView Not Storing Expected State

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, wpf-controls

I am encountering the following behavior which I do not understand. I have data that is *correctly* displayed in the `TreeView` as follows.

```
Sport
  > BaseBall
    > Apparel
    > Equiptment
        Glove
        Bat
  > Football
    > Helmet
  > Soccer
```

However, when I click on any node, the underlying node data is that of it's first child.

```
    Node Clicked            Actual Data
-------------------------------------------
    Sport                       Baseball
    Baseball                    Apparel
    Football                    Helmet
    Bat                         null
```

I have looked at many examples on the web and in books, but I cannot spot the issue; and I'm sure it's very simple.

**Edit** I have visually inspected each node in the debugger, as well as using a handy little code snippet from Mathew MacDonald's Pro WPF in C# 2010 that actually displays the types and value of every control in the TreeView.

**Edit** I have replaced initial code with an actual full application that reproduces the issue. It is the simplest example I could come up with.

The code(irrelevant sections removed):

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:this="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <this:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="ViewModel:MainWindow"></this:MainWindowViewModel>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

-

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:this="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel:MainWindow}">
    <TreeView x:Name="theTree" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OrgChart}"
              MouseUp="theTree_MouseUp">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Subordinates}" DataType="{x:Type this:OrgChartNodeViewModel}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Position.Title}"></TextBlock>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
</Window>
```

-

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void theTree_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Stack<DependencyObject> stack = new Stack<DependencyObject>();
        var it = e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;
        while (it != null)
        {
            it = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(it);
            stack.Push(it);
        }

        int level = 0;
        while (stack.Any())
        {
            Debug.Write("".PadLeft(level++));
            it = stack.Pop();
            if (it is TreeViewItem)
            {
                var item = it as TreeViewItem;
                OrgChartNodeViewModel vm = ((OrgChartNodeViewModel)((TreeViewItem)it).Items.CurrentItem);
                if (vm != null)
                    Debug.WriteLine(vm.Position.Title);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(it);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

-

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public List<OrgChartNodeViewModel> OrgChart { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Position ceo = new Position { Title = "CEO" };
        Position vp = new Position { Title = "VP" };
        Position boss = new Position { Title = "Boss" };
        Position worker = new Position { Title = "Worker" };

        OrgChartNodeViewModel root;
        OrgChartNodeViewModel node = new OrgChartNodeViewModel { Position = ceo };
        OrgChartNodeViewModel child = new OrgChartNodeViewModel { Position = vp };
        root = node;
        node.Subordinates.Add(child);
        node = child;
        child = new OrgChartNodeViewModel { Position = boss };
        node.Subordinates.Add(child);
        node = child;
        child = new OrgChartNodeViewModel { Position = worker };
        node.Subordinates.Add(child);

        OrgChart = new List<OrgChartNodeViewModel> { root };
    }
}
```

-

```
public class OrgChartNodeViewModel
{
    public Position Position { get; set; }
    public List<OrgChartNodeViewModel> Subordinates { get; set; }

    public OrgChartNodeViewModel()
    {
        Subordinates = new List<OrgChartNodeViewModel>();
    }
}
```

-

```
public class Position
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the output on my machine...

[image]

Comment: How are you verifying that the actual data is different from the clicked tree node?

Comment: I have visually inspected each node in the debugger, as well as using a handy little code snippet from Mathew MacDonald's Pro WPF in C# 2010 that actually displays the types and value of every control in the TreeView.

Comment: If the xaml you have shown is complete, the problem is that you aren't setting the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` on the `TreeView`, you are adding the template to the `TreeView.Items` collection. I'm surprised it isn't throwing an exception about you setting both `ItemsSource` and adding an item manually. Instead, the template should be in the `Resources` of your `UserControl`.

Comment: @AbeHeidebrecht I checked, and you are correct. I accidently left the resources section off. I have altered the XAML to reflect.

Comment: @JohnKraft Okay, well, I am not sure I can solve the problem based on the info here, but I can suggest some tools for debugging WPF programs. Have you tried Snoop (http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com)?
While not free, Mole has some great support too http://molosoft.com/latestversionsofmole/

Comment: @AbeHeidebrecht I removed the original code and replaced it with a simple sample app that repros the issue.

Comment: @JohnKraft That seems to work just fine. Are you concerned because the UI elements aren't generated until you expand the node? If so, I don't think there is anything you can do, because WPF lazily creates the UI elements when the nodes are first expanded.

Comment: @AbeHeidebrecht I must have a fundamental misunderstanding of the control then. :) When I select a node, I expect the node data to correspond to the displayed text. But, in the example I just posted, if I select the CEO node, the data it gives me is for the VP node. If you look at the output in the debug window, you can clearly see "VP" displayed when you click on the CEO node. I'll paste an image of that into the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try switching

```
OrgChartNodeViewModel vm = ((OrgChartNodeViewModel)((TreeViewItem)it).Items.CurrentItem);
```

to

```
OrgChartNodeViewModel vm = ((OrgChartNodeViewModel)viewItem.DataContext);
```

In your while loop, you want the `TreeViewItem.DataContext` rather than `Items.CurrentItem` which points to it's children(and only one exists until expanded firstly). Hence why you're seeing VP instead of CEO.

I'd prolly switch out the entire function to something like:

```
private void theTree_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
  var clickedItem = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
  if (clickedItem == null)
    return;
  var chartNode = clickedItem.DataContext as OrgChartNodeViewModel;
  if (chartNode != null)
    Debug.WriteLine(chartNode.Position.Title);
}
```

than iterate through the Visual-Tree to get a `TreeViewItem`. `DataContext` gets inherited in your xaml setup, so might as well use it to save doing redundant work.

Comment: Crud. I knew it had to be something simple. I was assuming (usually a bad idea) that the DataContext property would return me the DataContext that the tree was bound to, so I never even checked it. Thanks for the help!